# beanstalk mercurial version control with mercurialeclipse clone error

Tags: eclipse, mercurial, eclipse-juno, mercurialeclipse

I was having a mercurial repository on beanstalk. Then I installed mercurialeclipse on eclipse and then tried to clone the repository.

Eclipse SDK  Version: 4.2.2

MercurialEclipse    2.1.0.201304290948  mercurialeclipse.feature.group  MercurialEclipse project

URL - https://xxxx.hg.beanstalkapp.com/yyy

I am getting an error as " error: <html>"
But I can go through browser for the given location with given credentials.
Am i missing something ?

---

i tried with tortoseHg also. command was

% hg clone --verbose -- https://xxxx.hg.beanstalkapp.com/yyyy
URLError: <html>

[command returned code 255 Thu May 02 09:23:08 2013]

Comment: i tried with tortoseHg also. command was % hg clone --verbose -- https://xxxx.hg.beanstalkapp.com/yyyy
URLError: <html>

[command returned code 255 Thu May 02 09:23:08 2013]

Answer (score 0):

According to this page http://support.beanstalkapp.com/customer/portal/articles/602080-how-do-i-setup-tortoisehg-to-work-with-beanstalk- it should be accessed over ssh rather than https.

`ssh://hg@ACCOUNTNAME.beanstalkapp.com:/REPOSITORYNAME`

If in doubt get it working in TortoiseHg and once that's working clone using MercurialEclipse.